# Integrating paypal payment gate way to web app

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a widget called "ticket", Event Organizer uses ticket widget to sell tickets online.
When event organizer select ticket widget he will enter the ticket name,ticket cost,quantity of tickets,
and pay pal account id, after that he clicks on create ticket button it should place a button say "buy now" and 
organizers publishes the page.
At the other end when attendee clicks on "buy now" button it will redirect him to payment process, and gets
 the payment process done.After the successful transaction the money has to added to event organizers 
account and the number of tickets sold should be decremented in my web application.

Solutions:I have tried with "Buy Now Button" using JavaScript but i think it doesn't works out for our application.
Because here the organizer sells his tickets on our application ,so he needs to create his own button and place it
on our web application that is not to be any perfect idea
So kindly help me out in figuring out the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not like that every seller wont need to create their own button instead you can pass his paypal email id in the paypal form you generate

```
<input type ="hidden" name="business" value="seller_email_id" />
```

This will transfer the amount in that sellers account.